# Category List delete button

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I have copied `/components/com_content/views/category/default_articles.php` into my template and the overwrite is working fine.

I just don't know the line of code Joomla uses so I can add a Delete button next to the Edit button. This is on the Category List component.

Hope that makes sense.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ise no controller for articles in frontend, so you can't add delete button without customising `com_content` component. But there is option to unpublish / trash article in edit view. That's the best you can do in frontend from core component right now.

So if you need delete button, you should create your own component based on `com_content` and add articles controller, which has method to delete article. But bear in mind that Joomla! defaut flow is to trash article and only then delete it completely.

Comment: Thanks for this mate. So just getting this straight, there is no trash feature in the front end either? So I cannot have a "Delete" link that trashes the article?

Comment: Trashing (changing state with button/link) should be added with same controller as deleting. So no, only chaning state in article edit view.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will just stick with the core Joomla features.